# JavaScript replace dot with comma as decimal in this counter

Tags: javascript, decimal

I bodged this counter together from earlier posts here. I would like to change the decimal dot into a comma, but I tried this and the script stopped working. Furthermore, how can I get the euro sign and the number on one line? I am not 'breaking' anywhere so why is it the number always on a different line?

```
HTML:
&euro;<div class="counter">92.1</div> is the amount to pay

JavaScript:
function startCounter(){
    $('.counter').each(function (index) {
        var size = $(this).text().split(".")[1] ? $(this).text().split(".")[1].length : 0;
        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 2000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).text(parseFloat(now).toFixed(size));
            }
        });
    });
}   

startCounter();
```

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/fv7bctba/1/

I tried the `replace(/,/g, '.')` function. But I must say that I do not know for sure how to use it.

I also tried to change the `split` functions from . to , but then it would give me an NaN.

Comment: Show your work. What did you learn from stepping through this code with the debugger? What console output did you see when you did `console.log()` on the variables and the return values from your calls to `split()`? (Don't tell me; edit your question to show everyone what you found from doing that preliminary, [**required**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) pre-StackOverflow research).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)s are block level elements, which means that they will usually render with a newline before and after them. You can either style your `<div>` to be [`inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) or [`inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) or use an element that is already `inline`, such as a [`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. They are in line now!